# Почему веб-инспектор иногда не даёт редактировать стили?

Tags: браузер, инструменты-разработчика

Когда вызываю веб-инспектор и хочу отредактировать css код, бывает, что он не доступен для изменений. Шрифт при этом становится наклонным. Добавить свойства  можно, а вот изменить имеющиеся нет. 
Браузер web-kit.

Вот фото: 
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Fox Отклонил правку: убрал излишнее форматирование Почитайте пожалуйста тут  http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/ Одна из правок была слишком минорной и я не стал ради неё принимать правку.

Comment: Можешь привести пример разметки и стиля непосредственно в вопросе?

Comment: где определен и как добавляется на страницу класс `.choose-select`?

Comment: Дело в том, что периодически браузер загружает пустой файл style.css. И возможно подгружает его из кеша и поэтому не поменять.

Answer (score 1):

Такое бывает, если стили берутся из user-agent, или созданы вручную с помощью CSSOM.

Так же существует баг [Issue 387952: Dynamic css styles are not editable in chrome dev tools](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=387952), закрытый со статусом *WontFix*.

Суть заключается в том, что у данного стиля нет текстового представления где-либо, соответственно и редактировать нечего.

Воспроизвести можно довольно просто:

```js
var s = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(s);
s.sheet.insertRule('body { background:green;}'); // <- ага, вот эти стили
```

При просмотре стилей для элемента body можно увидеть следующую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]